# OLEDB v/s ODBC

Tags: odbc, oledb, driver

What is the difference between OLEDB and ODBC?  When do I use which and how do I know what I am looking at is a OLEDB driver v/s an ODBC driver?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

OLEDB and ODBC are two different database API's.  ODBC is an older standard and is actually not specific to windows - you can get Unix-based ODBC libraries.  OLEDB is a COM-based API for database connections.

There is a driver for wrapping ODBC with an OLEDB front-end if the database you are using does not come with a native OLEDB driver.  IIRC DB2/400 and Sybase OLEDB drivers (for example) use this method.

The ODBC administrator in Windows is only concerned with ODBC drivers.  Both ODBC and OLEDB can use connection strings, which have a slightly different format.  You can tell from the connection string - [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) has samples of connection strings for many different database drivers.

Edit: Oracle has a driver technology for every day of the week.

- Oracle have a [native OLEDB
  driver](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/ole_db/index.html) called 'Oracle provider
  for OLEDB' or some such.  If you're
  using ADO (non-.Net, which sits over
  OLEDB) this would be the preferred
  driver.
- They also have an [ODBC driver](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odbc/index.html)
  that would be (for example) useful for
  extracting from an Oracle database
  into MS-Access or with an application or system that does not support OLEDB.  For example, older Delphi/Oracle or Powerbuilder/Oracle apps will probably use this driver.
- Oracle also has an
  Oracle-specific interface called
  [OCI](http://www.orafaq.com/faqoci.htm).  This is the fastest
  interface if you're writing in C and
  will also work on non-windows
  plaforms but ties your application
  to Oracle.  Dynamic language bindings such as [cx_Oracle](http://python.net/crew/atuining/cx_Oracle/) for Python tend to be wrappers around OCI.
- If you're using .Net you probably
  want [ODP.Net](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html) rather than
  using the .Net provide for OLEDB.  This is the
  standard .Net interface library
  provided by Oracle.
- There are several [JDBC drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/htdocs/jdbc_faq.htm#02_00) for
  Oracle.  There is a type-2 driver
  which is a wrapper for OCI and a
  type-4 driver which is written
  natively in Java and communicates
  directly over the network to the
  server.  If you're using Java the type-4 driver is probably the best for most applications (you don't have to install a full Oracle client) unless you have a particular reason to need the type-2 driver.

Comment: So if I had options to connect to an Oracle DB say, from a Windows system, what would be the recommended option and why?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to give a good answer to that question without knowing what language you want to use.

Comment: Say it's .NET. And would the driver matter? I thought it depended on the OS.

Comment: Any driver with native components will be O/S specific; you would have to recompile for another platform.  I don't think ODP.Net directly supports Mono, which makes it Windows-only by default.  Type-4 JDBC drivers are portable - at least in theory - as they are pure Java.