# Unable to connect to Oracle DB using VBS

Tags: oracle, vbscript, oracle11g, adodb

I don't have an oracle DB installed on my machine. The DB location is on UNIX machine. I Want to run Insert queries in DB located on other VM. I had written one code iusing VB Script but that throws me an error while running the same. Please help me. Below is my code:

```vb
'Save the file with <filename>.vbs

Set dbMyDBConnection = CreateObject(“ADODB.Connection”)
ConnectionString = “(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.30.16.31)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=PUNDEV11)))”

strConnection = “Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=” & ConnectionString & “;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=” & strPassword & “;User ID=” & strUsername & “;Password=” & strPassword & “;”

dbMyDBConnection.Open strConnection
```

Also,  I checked replacing the provider to Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0 and OraOLEDB.Oracle.

I am using Windows 7 64 bit platform.

Error:

> Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed. Code : 800A0E7A Source : ADODB.Connection

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me how people expect you to help them without detailing the error they received. Just saying *"throws me an error"* isn't enough.

Comment: Sorry for less details: error:
Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed. Code : 800A0E7A Source : ADODB.Connection

Comment: It's fine just [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35888245/edit) and add the extra error details.

Answer (score 2):

Provider `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.x` is used to connect to an MS Access Database.

You must use the "Oracle Provider for OLE DB" provider. Would be like this:

```
ConnectionString = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.30.16.31)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=PUNDEV11)))"

Set dbMyDBConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbMyDBConnection.provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle"    
dbMyDBConnection.Open "Data Source=" & ConnectionString , strUsername , strPassword
```

The "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle" should be also possible. However, it has been [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for many years and it is available only for 32-bit.

```
dbMyDBConnection.provider = "MSDAORA"
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I checked with your input, but still getting the same issue. I switched the command prompt working directory to SysWOW64 directory in C:/Windows as well, but still it throws me "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed".

Comment: @subodhagnihotri Switching the command prompt to the `SysWOW64` directory will do *nothing* because providers are stored in the Windows Registry. You'll need to check you have the correct provider installed using the `%systemroot%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` *(Otherwise known as the 32 Bit ODBC Data Source Administrator)* program.

Comment: I assume you have to take the error message verbatim: Install the provider, you can download it from here: [Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) for Windows Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html)

Comment: @Lankymart, ODBC Data Source Administrator shows only the ODBC drivers (or providers), however an `OLE DB` Provider is not ODBC.See [ODBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity) vs. [OLE DB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_DB).

Comment: OLEDB is Microsoft proprietary but I'm fairly sure most OLEDB provider drivers have an ODBC interface under the hood. Usually they are shown in the Data Source Administrator regardless. See [what is the difference between OLE DB and ODBC data sources?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/103167/692942)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - I installed the components from the location you mentioned. Can you help me with further settings? I am very new to all these stuff.

Comment: Did you also install an Oracle (Instant) Client? It is required.

Comment: With the right architecture? (32 bit vs. 64 bit)? All components (i.e. your VBScript environment, Oracle Client and OLE DB Provider) must be the same!

Comment: 64 bit installation and Yes all the components Installed

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You need to install a 32-bit driver and need to use that driver and its corresponding connection string from here in a 32-bit terminal. If you get the combination wrong, you will hit with all sort of errors.

- https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle12c-windows-downloads.html
- https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-in-oraclient11g_home1/
- https://www.tipandtrick.net/how-to-open-and-run-32-bit-command-prompt-in-64-bit-x64-windows/

Long answer: I faced the same problem and wasted a few days trying to get it working. Here I posted a detailed step-by-step answer on how to get this working.

[How to connect to oracle database using VBScript and UFT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61188518/how-to-connect-to-oracle-database-using-vbscript-and-uft)