# How to allow multiple users to use Access frontend with MySQL backend without installing MySQL ODBC driver

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

I am wondering what is the best, most efficient way to make this transition from an MS Access backend to a MySQL backend when it comes to multiple users accessing the database.

Currently, there are about 20 users that use this Access database in a shared folder. If I migrate the backend to MySQL and link the tables using ODBC, I have that I will need to install the MySQL ODBC driver on all of these users' devices.

This doesn't seem like that great of a solution, since if a user gets a new device, a new user needs access, etc., they will also have to install a MySQL ODBC driver to use the database.

Or, does it work that only 1 user needs the driver installed. Then, this user can link the frontend database to the backend. Now since the database is linked, other users can use it without requiring an MySQL ODBC driver?

I am aware that with this many users, the application should be migrated to a web solution, but that is not an option right now.

Comment: Each user needs their own copy of the front-end (UI) file, and that instance of Access needs to communicate with the MySQL server, so yes, each client needs to have the MySQL ODBC driver installed. It seems silly to worry about one more program (MySQL Connector/ODBC) "if a user gets a new device" when you've already said that the build will need to have Office set up anyway.

Comment: Each user should run own copy of frontend on their computer so each will have to connect to backend by whatever method. Don't think can avoid installing ODBC driver. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53753099/dao-dsn-less-connection-vs-ado-connection

Comment: The driver is freely available. You can write code detecting if it's present, and either redirecting users to the download site if it isn't, or, with some more work, actually download and install the driver for them. Installing the driver shouldn't really be an issue.