# SAS dsnless connection to SQL server not working even if OLEDB is installed

Tags: sql-server, sas, odbc

I am trying to setup a DSN less connection to SQL server as follows:

```
libname sqwireno sqlsvr noprompt='Driver=SQLServer;Address=TOCGDMS,1433;Database=DMS1;
       UID=s11111;PWD=Test;' schema=dbo;
```

ERROR: The SQLSVR engine cannot be found.
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.

I am using SAS 9.4 on windows and have verified that SAS Access to OLEDB is installed.

What did I do wrong

Comment: OLEDB uses providers while ODBC uses drivers. You are attempting an ODBC connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows environments, clients like SAS can make OLEDB and ODBC connections ([two distinct APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103167/what-is-the-difference-between-ole-db-and-odbc-data-sources)) to relational databases. SAS/ACCESS using `libname` supports both forms requiring those specific features installed (check: `proc setinit; run;`). Below are examples of DSN-less connections but DSNs (Data Source Name) as supported by all three:

**[ODBC](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=acreldb&docsetTarget=p0bu3zsz1a08ton1msxdx1jo45np.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)** *(requires 'SQL Server' or other driver installed)*

```
libname sqldata odbc noprompt="driver=SQL Server; Server=servername; user=username; 
                               pwd=password; database=databasename" schema=myschema;
```

**[OLEDB](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=acreldb&docsetTarget=p1a9wh7qwv6vc9n18arz94i379q0.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)** *(requires 'SQLOLEDB' or other provider installed)*

```
libname sqldata oledb user=username password=password datasource=servername schema=myschema
                      provider=sqloledb properties=('initial catalog'=databasename);
```

Do note: Microsoft allows free downloads of latest [ODBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and [OLEDB provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) for SQL Server (where 'SQLOLEDB' is now [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) for 'MSOLEDBSQL').

---

Additionally, SAS supports an SQL Server engine connection which possibly offers more specific MSSQL features than the above two interfaces which are generalized for *any* database or data source:

**[SQLSERV](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=acreldb&docsetTarget=n0gz66qe8msnkyn1jgnhrr0l2k8y.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)** *(using SAS ODBC driver)*

```
libname mssql sqlsvr noprompt="driver={SAS ACCESS to SQL Server}; server=servername; 
                               database=databasename; uid=username; pwd=password" schema=myshema;
```

In fact, your connection may work with appropriate punctuation such as `{...}` in `Driver` argument.

```
libname sqwireno sqlsvr noprompt="Driver={SQL Server};Server=TOCGDMS,1433;Database=DMS1;    
                                  UID=s11111;PWD=Test;" schema=dbo;
```